# Facebook Graph API - Getting error 2207026 when trying to upload video

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ffmpeg, instagram, supabase

I try to upload a video via the graph API but as the title states, I get an error that states that I use an unsupported video format.

I thought maybe the original video file doesn't match the video specifications as defined on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#video-specifications so I wrote a function to convert the file to match the specification, using ffmpeg with the following command (I tried many different ones, but this is the last one I tried)

`ffmpeg -i ${tmpInFile} -vf format=yuv420p -vf scale=-2:720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -movflags +faststart -c:v libx264 -b:v 3M -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest -f mp4 ${tmpOutFile}`

Unfortunately, the error persists.

Here's the complete process:

First I use `await fetch('/api/convert-mp4', { method: 'POST', body: file });` to send the uploaded video file to the backend.

Next I get the blob data from the request with `const blob = await request.blob();`.

Then I create a temporary file with `await fs.writeFile(tmpInFile, await blob.stream())`.

Then I call ffmpeg with the above command mentioned above and then read the file with `const buffer = await fs.readFile(tmpOutFile);`.

Then I send the buffer as response body back to the client with `return {status: 200,body: buffer}`.

Then I get the blob data from the response with `const blob = await convertVideoResponse.blob();`.

Finally I convert it back into a file object with
`const convertedFile = new File([blob], file.name, { type: 'video/mp4' });`

This file I upload to Supabase Storage (https://supabase.com/storage), and get a publicly accessible url (which I confirmed by opening it in an incognito tab).

In the supabase dashboard I can see the video file has the correct media container (video/mp4) and the file size is small enough.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue?

Edit:

By changing the ffmpeg command to use h265 instead of h254 `ffmpeg -i ${tmpInFile} -vf format=yuv420p -vf scale=-2:1350 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -movflags +faststart -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -an -x265-params crf=25 -b:v 3M -c:a copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest -f mp4 ${tmpOutFile}` I managed to get it to work for some videos but not all, which confuses me, as I assumed that the video attributes should be the same for all videos processed by the same command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue, and GOT IT TO WORK!

### TL;DR

Make sure your video is not too long

### More details

In the end I came up with this as an example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-c:v libx264 -aspect 16:9 -crf 18 \
-vf "scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw)/2:(720-ih)/2" \
-fpsmax 60 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -t 59 -y output.mp4
```

On some flags some details about what and why:

- -c:v libx264 → You need to compress with [Video codec: HEVC or H264, progressive scan, closed GOP, 4:2:0 chroma subsampling](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#video-specifications)
- --aspect and `-vf "scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw)/2:(720-ih)/2"` → As I want my video's always to be within 1280x720, padding added if needed.
- fpsmax → Make sure you do not exceed the framerate of 60fps
- -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 1 → For ["AAC, 48khz sample rate maximum, 1 or 2 channels (mono or stereo)"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#video-specifications)
- -t 59 → Limit to under 1 minute, as that is the max for a video!

I think **the most important thing here is the `-t 59` as the API only supports files up to one minute!**

After this, everything worked